# How to create a separate web page menu to be used only on one of my web pages?

Tags: navigation, blocks

My site has a main menu displayed at the top of each page. But one of my pages is about a Parade we host, and it has a lot of content.

I would like to create a menu just on the Parade web page. Every option I have looked at has edited the main site menu.

But how do I create a separate menu just to be displayed on my specific pages?

Answer (score 3):

Add a new menu to the site.

Go to Structure > Menus > Add Menu

Once you have added a menu, and the links, this menu will now be available as a block.

Go to Structure > Blocks and assign the new menu to a region.

under that block settings, you can define which URL you would like the block to display on. Set that to the URL of your page, and you're good to go.

Comment: Looks like we posted a fairly similar answer more or less at the same moment. Are you sure you don't need to clear the cache before you're "good to go"?

Comment: Possibly. I've just created one as a test and didn't need to clear the cache to see it appear.

Comment: I will try and clear the cache if need be. Thank you both!

Comment: I'd be interested if you could get it to work without clearing the cache first ...

Comment: It worked for me and I did not clear the cache. I am currently working on making the menu horizontal - it is in bullets currently. I assume this has to do with our themes, but our main menu is horizontal and this one is not, which is strange to me. I am new to drupal if you couldn't tell!

Comment: Nevermind - I have changed the CSS and it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Would the [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module help here? You could use the standard menu system to create a custom menu and then expose some or all of that menu as a block that could be added to new or existing region in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1: Create the Parade menu

Navigate to `admin/structure/menu/add` in your site and add a new (custom) menu you want. Add at least the "Title" of the menu (like *Parade menu*), save it, and it will show up in `admin/structure/menu` also. From there you can start to add menu items (which will be the "Parade related menu items" you are looking for).

## Step 2: Make the menu visible

Head over to `admin/structure/block` to indicate in which region of your theme you want that newly added menu (*Parade menu*) to be shown.

Tune the "block visibility settings" so that this block is ONLY shown on your "Parade Web page".

## Step 3: Clear the cache

And don't forget to clear the cache (since you're changing things that are cache sensitive ...). I think "menu" cache should be sufficient, but to be sure I usually just clear all caches ...